# Why The assembly is not permitted to be used by an ObjectDataSource component when exporting Telerik Report from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-reporting

**An error has occurred while processing Table 'table2': The assembly "AssemblyName.Context, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" is not permitted to be used by an ObjectDataSource component. Please include it in an AssemblyReferences element in the Telerik.Reporting configuration section of your application configuration file.**

I am using below code for export report in pdf.

```
 public static System.IO.Stream GerRep(List<EquipmentSearchResult> list)
        {
            EquipmentExportReportT report = new EquipmentExportReportT();

            report.ReportParameters["BaseLocationName"].Value = "MyTest";
            //report.DataSource = list;

            ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();

            // set any deviceInfo settings if necessary
            System.Collections.Hashtable deviceInfo = new System.Collections.Hashtable();

            Telerik.Reporting.TypeReportSource typeReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.TypeReportSource();

            // reportName is the Assembly Qualified Name of the report
            typeReportSource.TypeName = typeof(EquipmentExportReportT).AssemblyQualifiedName;

            RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("XLS", typeReportSource, deviceInfo);

            string fileName = result.DocumentName + "." + result.Extension;
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(result.DocumentBytes, 0, result.DocumentBytes.Length);
            }

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(result.DocumentBytes);
            ms.Position = 0;

            return ms;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the configuration issue, you need to apply some setting on the web.config file.

In this case the application configuration file needs to be modified and the name of the assembly needs to be added in a new node within the AssemblyReferences element contents in the following manner:

```
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="Telerik.Reporting" type="Telerik.Reporting.Configuration.ReportingConfigurationSection, Telerik.Reporting" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
  </configSections>

  <Telerik.Reporting>
    <assemblyReferences>
      <add name="yourAssemblyName"/>
    </assemblyReferences>
  </Telerik.Reporting>

</configuration>
```

I hope this will resolve your problem. Cheers :)